# any way to bind bash file to binary file

Tags: linux, bash

need to create a executable binary file out of a bash file. is it possible from rationale? thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to hide (sensitive information from) the command line parameters of a program, is that the question?

Comment: Well, other than patching the kernel, I think the answer is "no, you can't do that". But anyway, the way this question is phrased has a bit of an XY problem smell: you've already chosen a solution and only that solution is mentioned in the question title. To your credit, you did also mention your actual goal, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) is what you need.
Also check the following question:

[How to convert a shell script into a binary executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64762/how-to-convert-a-shell-script-into-a-binary-executable)

**Edit**

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830823/hiding-secret-from-command-line-parameter-on-unix) explains why it is hard and how to use some tricks to hide the argument from `ps`. Most of them require the source code of the program, and some of them are making use of the bugs in `ps` and may not be portable.

Note that in the implementation of `shc`, if you check the source file generated by it, you will see there is a macro `hide_z` defined, which is later used as the number of space to be padded before the actual script. However this trick does not work well in my new linux box (I tried it before and it worked, sorry again for not doubling checking before posting an answer) which is running on CentOS 7.4.

Comment: Sure, you just need some additional work. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I am really sorry that I may have mistaken something. I may not be able to solve your original question but anyway I will post some related information above so that it may help others who come across this page.